# Vuejs Displaying a component multiple times with Axios in it

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have been trying to figure out this for a hours but no luck. I have 2 components. The first component is dynamic and the second component just gets the user geolocation. The geolocation is then displayed in the first component.

My problem is that I display the first component a few times on the page and every time it is displayed it makes a GET request which is inefficient . If I display the component 3 times it will make 3 GET requests.

What would be the best way to rewrite this?

Thanks for the help

Component 1:

```
<template>
    <section id="under-info">
        THe user is from <ip_info></ip_info>
    </section>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
    }
</script>
```

Component 2:

```
<template>

    <span id="user-city">
        {{value}}
    </span>


</template>

<script>
    export default {
        mounted: function () {
            this.$nextTick(function () {
                this.getIpInfo(this.param)
            })
        },
        props:['param'],
        data: function () {
            return {
                value:null
            }
        },
        methods:{
            getIpInfo(){
                var vm = this
                delete axios.defaults.headers.common["X-Requested-With"];
                delete axios.defaults.headers.common["X-CSRF-TOKEN"];
                axios
                    .get('http://api.ipstack.com/check?access_key=?',{
                        timeout: 1000
                    })
                    .then(function(response) {
                        vm.value = response.data['city]
                    })
            }
    },
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Is it possible to get more than 1 location from your geolocation api?  if not, then you'll have to make an api call for each location anyways

Comment: My problem is that for the same user I display the component 3 times on the same page and each time I display it, a GET request is called which I don't like. I would like to call the GET method once and display the user location 3 times.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the code where you want to reuse this value 3x in a component.

```
<template>
    <div>
        The user is from {{location}}, and {{location}} is a great place.  They have a baseball team in {{location}}
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        mounted: function () {
            this.$nextTick(function () {
               if(this.needLocation){
                this.getIpInfo(this.param)
               }
            })
        },
        props:['param', 'needLocation'],
        data: function () {
            return {
                location:null
            }
        },
        methods:{
            getIpInfo(){
              this.location = //results from your API call
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: My first component is inserted through out different blog posts but in some it is not. With your suggestion, I would need to make an API call every time even though the blog might not need it. All my blogs are displayed dynamically from a database.

Comment: Can you pass in a prop that reflects the need to make an api call?  Then just wrap the api request with that prop?  Updating answer above.

Comment: You could wrap the entire $nextTick function with the condition instead if you like